# How to solve `print_req_error: I/O error, unable to read superblock` hard disk drive error after notebook have been dropped?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hardware-failure

I have occasionally dropped my laptop Acer Aspire E 15 which caused to disk damage (alongside with matrix damage but there is no problem since I can use external display to my laptop with potential replacing the matrix). There is no possibility to boot up from internal disk but I can boot OS from bootable usb. After booting from usb I have tried to open disk which results in a long trying to do this and after long period of time I've got this error message:

```
Unable to access “285 GB Volume”
Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/ubuntu/a349773e-dc98-453e-bd40-6b9a419da8b3: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/ubuntu/a349773e-dc98-453e-bd40-6b9a419da8b3"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb5,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I've issued this command from terminal I've got the following response:

```
[19031.191978] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[19033.151287] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[19033.151303] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[19033.151336] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[19033.151341] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[19033.151346] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[19033.151351] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 51 23 78 02 00 00 02 00
[19033.151355] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1361278978
[19033.151397] ata1: EH complete
[19033.151409] EXT4-fs (sdb5): unable to read superblock
```

Is it possible to fix this problem somehow programmatically or this problem could be (if it's possible) solved only by hardware specialists?

---

### **UPDATE**

After even more time, the result of opening the `Acer` folder was obtained with the following error message:

```
Unable to access “Acer”
Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/ubuntu/Acer: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sdb4" "/media/ubuntu/Acer"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb4': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

So I have to use the Windows operating system to try to fix the error using the chkdsk utility (using `chkdsk /f`)? There is no utility with similar functionality in Linux?

Comment: If the drive has fall damage, I wouldn't expect it to work at all. If it still does, you should look into backing it up ASAP, using a tool like dd_rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Use some live linux starting from a USB stick such as Knoppix or the small Gparted.iso (~300 MB) to run smartmontools and post your error log here.

The syntax is like
smartctl -a /dev/sdX > mylog.txt

Replace the "X" by the drive letter in question. Copy the mylog.txt file to another USB stick. Post the log file here.
It might be necessary to duplicate the drive using ddrescue.

> So I have to use the Windows operating system to try to fix the error using the chkdsk utility (using chkdsk /f)? There is no utility with similar functionality in Linux?

Nobody will tell you as you did not tell which file systems you used.

Depending on the outcome paying a professional recovery service might be necessary.

> I have occasionally dropped my laptop Acer Aspire E 15 which caused to disk damage

If you are used to occasionally dropping your laptop you might either build a rubber housing for it or get a hardened military-style laptop unless you refrain your costly habits.